# What is the correct procedure for removing expired certificates in the Mac OS X Keychain

Tags: macos, certificate

If I open the app Keychain Access from the Utilities directory I can filter out a list of certificated that the OS uses.

Filtering to show all certificates then sorting by date and I can see that a good portion of the certificates have expired.

Do we just wait for an update or OS update to solve this or are we supposed to manually intervene?

What is the correct procedure? If they are expired, they will kick an error for the certificate if I access it. That hasn't happened to me yet so far, making me think these are rather esoteric certificates and I need not worry too much.

However, it concerns security, and I would rather have them not be there and get an error than get another error where I have to read through the certificate to see why it is not working.

What is the suggested methodology for dealing with the expired certificates in keychain manager in Mac OS x?